# How to use CSS on HTML made by TextEdit?

Tags: html, css, formatting, textedit

After writing a document with the formatting I was going for in TextEdit on a mac, I used "save as HTML" to get the HTML. However, the HTML file is very strange(to get the right formatting, and right now I can't get it to use my CSS file.

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <link href="lyrics.css" rel="lyrics" type="text/css">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">
  <meta name="CocoaVersion" content="1038.36">
  <style type="text/css">
    p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 13.0px Verdana}
    p.p2 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 13.0px Verdana; min-height: 16.0px}
    p.p3 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; line-height: 24.0px; font: 13.0px Verdana}
    p.p4 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; line-height: 24.0px; font: 13.0px Verdana; min-height: 16.0px}
    span.Apple-tab-span {white-space:pre}
  </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #468966; text-color: #FFF0A5;">
<p class="p1">F#maj<span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>G#7</p>
<p class="p1">Baiana que entra no samba e só fica parada</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>G#m7</p>
<p class="p1">Não samba, não dança, não bole nem nada</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>C#7<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>F#maj<span class="Apple-tab-span">   </span>F#7</p>
<p class="p1">Não sabe deixar a mocidade louca</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>Hmaj<span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>A#m</p>
<p class="p1">Baiana é aquela que entra no samba de qualquer maneira</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>D#7<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>G#m</p>
<p class="p1">Que mexe, remexe, dá nó nas cadeiras</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>C#7<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span> <span class="Apple-converted-space">  </span>F#maj</p>
<p class="p1">Deixando a moçada com água na boca</p>
<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p1">F#maj<span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>G#7</p>
<p class="p1">Baiana que entra no samba e só fica parada</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>G#m7</p>
<p class="p1">Não samba, não dança, não bole nem nada</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>C#7<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>F#maj<span class="Apple-tab-span">   </span>F#7</p>
<p class="p1">Não sabe deixar a mocidade louca</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>Hmaj<span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>A#m</p>
<p class="p1">Baiana é aquela que entra no samba de qualquer maneira</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>D#7<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>G#m</p>
<p class="p1">Que mexe, remexe, dá nó nas cadeiras</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>C#7<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span> <span class="Apple-converted-space">  </span>F#maj<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span>D#7b9</p>
<p class="p1">Deixando a moçada com água na boca</p>
<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-converted-space">    </span>G#m<span class="Apple-tab-span">  </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>C#7</p>
<p class="p1">A falsa baiana quando entra no samba</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-converted-space">      </span>F#maj</p>
<p class="p1">Ninguém se incomoda, ninguém bate palma</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>G#m<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>D#7</p>
<p class="p1">Ninguém abre a roda, ninguém grita ôba</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-converted-space">    </span>F#maj<span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span> <span class="Apple-converted-space">  </span>F#7</p>
<p class="p1">Salve a Bahia, senhor</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-converted-space">    </span>Hmaj<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span> <span class="Apple-converted-space">  </span>D#m7<span class="Apple-tab-span">  </span></p>
<p class="p1">Mas a gente gosta quando uma baiana</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>A#m<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span> D#7</p>
<p class="p1">Samba direitinho, de cima embaixo</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-converted-space"> <span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span></span>G#m<span class="Apple-tab-span">  </span></p>
<p class="p1">Revira os olhinhos dizendo</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-converted-space">   <span class="Apple-tab-span">  </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>     </span>C#7<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span> <span class="Apple-converted-space">  <span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span></span>F#maj</p>
<p class="p3">E diz: "Eu sou filha de São Salvador".</p>
<p class="p4"><br></p>
<p class="p4"><br></p>
<p class="p4"><br></p>
<p class="p1">F#maj<span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>G#7</p>
<p class="p1">Baiana que entra no samba e só fica parada</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>G#m7</p>
<p class="p1">Não samba, não dança, não bole nem nada</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>C#7<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>F#maj<span class="Apple-tab-span">   </span>F#7</p>
<p class="p1">Não sabe deixar a mocidade louca</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>Hmaj<span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>A#m</p>
<p class="p1">Baiana é aquela que entra no samba de qualquer maneira</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>D#7<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>G#m</p>
<p class="p1">Que mexe, remexe, dá nó nas cadeiras</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>C#7<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span> <span class="Apple-converted-space">  </span>F#maj</p>
<p class="p1">Deixando a moçada com água na boca</p>
<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p1">F#maj<span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>G#7</p>
<p class="p1">Baiana que entra no samba e só fica parada</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>G#m7</p>
<p class="p1">Não samba, não dança, não bole nem nada</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>C#7<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>F#maj<span class="Apple-tab-span">   </span>F#7</p>
<p class="p1">Não sabe deixar a mocidade louca</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>Hmaj<span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>A#m</p>
<p class="p1">Baiana é aquela que entra no samba de qualquer maneira</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>D#7<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>G#m</p>
<p class="p1">Que mexe, remexe, dá nó nas cadeiras</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>C#7<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span> <span class="Apple-converted-space">  </span>F#maj<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span>D#7b9</p>
<p class="p1">Deixando a moçada com água na boca</p>
<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-converted-space">    </span>G#m<span class="Apple-tab-span">  </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>C#7</p>
<p class="p1">A falsa baiana quando entra no samba</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-converted-space">      </span>F#maj</p>
<p class="p1">Ninguém se incomoda, ninguém bate palma</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>G#m<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>D#7</p>
<p class="p1">Ninguém abre a roda, ninguém grita ôba</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-converted-space">    </span>F#maj<span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span> <span class="Apple-converted-space">  </span>F#7</p>
<p class="p1">Salve a Bahia, senhor</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-converted-space">    </span>Hmaj<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span> <span class="Apple-converted-space">  </span>D#m7<span class="Apple-tab-span">  </span></p>
<p class="p1">Mas a gente gosta quando uma baiana</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>A#m<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span> D#7</p>
<p class="p1">Samba direitinho, de cima embaixo</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-converted-space"> <span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span></span>G#m<span class="Apple-tab-span">  </span></p>
<p class="p1">Revira os olhinhos dizendo</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-converted-space">   <span class="Apple-tab-span">  </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>     </span>C#7<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span> <span class="Apple-converted-space">  <span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span></span>F#maj</p>
<p class="p3">E diz: "Eu sou filha de São Salvador".</p>
<p class="p4"><br></p>
<p class="p4"><br></p>
<p class="p4"><br></p>
<p class="p1">F#maj<span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>G#7</p>
<p class="p1">Baiana que entra no samba e só fica parada</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>G#m7</p>
<p class="p1">Não samba, não dança, não bole nem nada</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>C#7<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>F#maj<span class="Apple-tab-span">   </span>F#7</p>
<p class="p1">Não sabe deixar a mocidade louca</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>Hmaj<span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>A#m</p>
<p class="p1">Baiana é aquela que entra no samba de qualquer maneira</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>D#7<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>G#m</p>
<p class="p1">Que mexe, remexe, dá nó nas cadeiras</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>C#7<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span> <span class="Apple-converted-space">  </span>F#maj</p>
<p class="p1">Deixando a moçada com água na boca</p>
<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p1">F#maj<span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>G#7</p>
<p class="p1">Baiana que entra no samba e só fica parada</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>G#m7</p>
<p class="p1">Não samba, não dança, não bole nem nada</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>C#7<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>F#maj<span class="Apple-tab-span">   </span>F#7</p>
<p class="p1">Não sabe deixar a mocidade louca</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>Hmaj<span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>A#m</p>
<p class="p1">Baiana é aquela que entra no samba de qualquer maneira</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>D#7<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>G#m</p>
<p class="p1">Que mexe, remexe, dá nó nas cadeiras</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>C#7<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span> <span class="Apple-converted-space">  </span>F#maj<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span>D#7b9</p>
<p class="p1">Deixando a moçada com água na boca</p>
<p class="p4"><br></p>
<p class="p4"><br></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-converted-space">    </span>G#m<span class="Apple-tab-span">  </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>C#7</p>
<p class="p1">A falsa baiana quando entra no samba</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-converted-space">      </span>F#maj</p>
<p class="p1">Ninguém se incomoda, ninguém bate palma</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>G#m<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>D#7</p>
<p class="p1">Ninguém abre a roda, ninguém grita ôba</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-converted-space">    </span>F#maj<span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span> <span class="Apple-converted-space">  </span>F#7</p>
<p class="p1">Salve a Bahia, senhor</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-converted-space">    </span>Hmaj<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span> <span class="Apple-converted-space">  </span>D#m7<span class="Apple-tab-span">  </span></p>
<p class="p1">Mas a gente gosta quando uma baiana</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>A#m<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span> D#7</p>
<p class="p1">Samba direitinho, de cima embaixo</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-converted-space"> <span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span></span>G#m<span class="Apple-tab-span">  </span></p>
<p class="p1">Revira os olhinhos dizendo</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-converted-space">   <span class="Apple-tab-span">  </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span>     </span>C#7<span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span> <span class="Apple-converted-space">  <span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span></span>F#maj</p>
<p class="p3">E diz: "Eu sou filha de São Salvador".</p>
<p class="p4"><br></p>
<p class="p4"><br></p>
<p class="p1">Baiana que entra no samba e só fica parada ( baiana kej entra no samba so fika parada )<span class="Apple-tab-span">  </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span></p>
<p class="p1">Não samba, não dança, não bole nem nada ( nå kunte nå samba nå bole nem nanda )<span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></p>
<p class="p1">Não sabe deixar a mocidade louca ( nå sabe deikjar a mosidade låka )</p>
<p class="p1">Baiana é aquela que entra no samba de qualquer maneira ( baiana e akela kej entra no samba de kåke manera )</p>
<p class="p1">Que mexe, remexe, dá nó nas cadeiras ( kej mesj, hemesj, da nå nas kaderas ) <span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></p>
<p class="p1">Deixando a moçada com água na boca ( deikjando mosada ko agua na boka )</p>
<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p1">A falsa baiana quando entra no samba ( A falsa baiana kvand entra nå samba )<span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></p>
<p class="p1">Ninguém se incomoda, ninguém bate palma ( ninkes inkomoda, ninkem batje palma )</p>
<p class="p1">Ninguém abre a roda, ninguém grita ôba ( ninge abra oda, ningen grita oba )</p>
<p class="p1">Salve a Bahia, senhor ( Salv a Bahia, siho )<span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></p>
<p class="p1">Mas a gente gosta quando uma baiana ( Mas a kjenkje goshta kvandoma baiana )<span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></p>
<p class="p1">Samba direitinho, de cima embaixo ( he kebra deritjinjo desima imbasj )<span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></p>
<p class="p1">Revira os olhinhos dizendo ( revir os olhinos )<span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></p>
<p class="p1">E diz: "Eu sou filha de São Salvador". ( e dis "e så filja di så salvador" )<span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></p>
<p class="p4"><br></p>
<p class="p4"><br></p>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
p.p1
{
    color: #FFF0A5;
}

p.p2
{
    color: #FFF0A5;
    text-color: #FFF0A5;
}

body
{
    background-color: #468966;
}
```

The CSS doesn't affect the HTML file at all! What's the problem?

Comment: Are the files saved in the same directory? And is your CSS file named lyrics.css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<link href="lyrics.css" rel="lyrics" type="text/css">
```

Should be `rel="stylesheet"`.

Answer (score 0):

**If I understood you question????**

Because you are overriding your css rules. You are loading css file into html first, then override for example `background-color: #468966`. Either leave the code in html or load the css.

The only case you want to use style after your css and not to override anything, is to have different `id` or `class` names.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was something I did in desperation after the CSS didn't work.

Comment: you don't have to be sorry about anything, also use rel="stylesheet"

Answer (score 0):

Setting Textedit to plan text mode might help with the formatting, but I would try using TextWrangler: http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/ though, it very popular for web coding and free.